# Why Silverlight projects are not built concurrently?

Tags: silverlight, concurrency, build, devenv

I have a solution with quite a few Silverlight projects. I have noticed a strange thing - when I build in Visual Studio IDE with the max concurrent builds set to 8, then the Silverlight projects are built sequentially.

Other projects (non Silverlight) are built in parallel.

So, here is the build logs:

- when Max Concurrent Builds is 1 - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZvguRmda
- when it is 8 - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FGFHt54f

Why don't Silverlight builds interleave?

Comment: Presumably there are no dependencies between these SL projects which dictate they must be built sequentially?

Comment: Well, some of them may depend on others, sure. However, not to the extent that no two SL projects could be built in parallel. There is a clear division between infrastructure assemblies and individual screens. The screens do not depend on each other and should be able to be built concurrently.